# Simplify expressions with modulo 2 (Boolean algebra)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Suppose I have a (Boolean algebra) expression

```
a = p1 x^2 + p2 x (x-1) + 3 p3 + 4 p4 x
```

where `p1`, ..., `p4` are either 0 or 1, and `x` is an integer. I want to simplify `Mod[a,2]` (the motivation is that `a Pi` is the phase angle of some complex number, so `a Pi` can be shifted by integer multiples of `2 Pi`). Since `x(x-1)` and `4x` are always even numbers, and `x^2`, `x` have the same parity, we have the simpler expression

```
a = p1 x + p3   ( mod 2 )
```

How can I achieve such simplifications in Mathematica?

Comment: `Factor[a , Modulus -> 2]`?

Comment: This gives `p1 x^2 + p2 x(x+1) + p3`, which is not the simplest possible expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are working in a Boolean algebra (this should be stated explicitly). So there are reduction relations. We'll compute those first.

```
a = p1 x^2 + p2 x (x - 1) + 3 p3 + 4 p4 x;
vars = Variables[a];
reductions = Map[#^2 + # &, vars]

(* Out[83]= {p3 + p3^2, p4 + p4^2, x + x^2, p2 + p2^2, p1 + p1^2} *)
```

Now use `PolynomialReduce` to apply these relations.

```
PolynomialReduce[a, reductions, vars, Modulus -> 2][[2]]

(* Out[84]= p3 + p1 x *)
```